# Capture 'enter' of view globally in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am building an application using ionic and there are a few settings I need to reset on enter of any view in my application. Is there a way to capture the enter event of view globally in one place like a super method? So that I do not need to replicate the reset settings in every view's enter event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $stateChangeSuccess event inside run method or in your global controller to identify view change/enter.

```
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        console.log("Entered to view");
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to track state changes and then execute your code when the route is changed and a certain route is visited, for example:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ ... })
```

You can find more details here: [State Change Events](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events).